# Link to fonts with Vue Cli 3

Tags: javascript, vue.js, sass, vue-cli-3

I'm trying to link my @font-face to my font folder (assets/fonts) on a project created by vue cli 3 with vue 2

[arborescence](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wZxKV.png)

assets/sass/utilities/fonts.sass

```
@font-face
  font-family: 'NeuzeitGroteskBold'
  src: url($font-path + 'NeuzeitGroteskBold/neuzeitgro-bol-webfont.eot')
  src: url($font-path + 'NeuzeitGroteskBold/neuzeitgro-bol-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
       url($font-path + 'NeuzeitGroteskBold/neuzeitgro-bol-webfont.woff2') format('font-woff2'),
       url($font-path + 'NeuzeitGroteskBold/neuzeitgro-bol-webfont.woff') format('font-woff'),
       url($font-path + 'NeuzeitGroteskBold/neuzeitgro-bol-webfont.ttf') format('font-truetype')
  font-weight: normal
  font-style: normal
```

assets/sass/app.sass

```
@charset "utf-8"
$font-path: '~@/assets/fonts/'
@import 'utilities/all'
```

I already tried ../../fonts or assets/fonts, to put it in the public folder or with font-url but nothing worked...

I have no error message, fonts are just not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok it's because the `format('font-woff')` that is use to fix another bug is not correct

It's working with `format('woff')`